# What is the difference between combining paths in those 2 ways?

Tags: .net, powershell

Can you explain what is the difference between

```
$attachment = [String]::Concat($workingDir,"\", $fileName)
```

and

```
$attachment = [IO.Path]::Combine($workingDir, $fileName)
```

when it comes to combining paths in Powershell?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Consider a situation where `$workingDir` has a trailing backslash and `$fileName` has a leading one, e.g.:

```
$workingDir = "C:\foo\"
$fileName   = "\bar.txt"
```

The 2 commands will produce the following results:

```
PS C:\> [String]::Concat($workingDir, "\", $fileName)
C:\foo\\\bar.txt
PS C:\> [IO.Path]::Combine($workingDir, $fileName)
\bar.txt
```

In PowerShell it's better to use `Join-Path`:

```
PS C:\> Join-Path $workingDir $fileName
C:\foo\bar.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

The `Path.Combine` method is semantically aware of folder paths.  For example, if `$workingDir` was `"c:\"` then the `String.Concat` sample would produce a path with two adjacent backslashes.

Comment: Example (using C#, but the output will be the same in any caller): http://pastie.org/8051557