# Defining path to a file with $PSScriptRoot

Tags: powershell, path, filepath

This is not exactly asking for help, more like kind of curiosity. I have a path to a file defined like this in my script:

```cs
$RootDir = $PSScriptRoot
$ExcelFile = $RootDir + "\" + $File + ".xlsx"
```

The `$File` variable is defined earlier in the script. This version works perfectly fine, but when I tried to simplify it like this to a single row, it didn't work:

```cs
$ExcelFile = $PSScriptRoot + "\" + $File + ".xlsx"
```

Any idea why the second version does not work? It says that the file could not be found. I can't see any logical reason for it.

Comment: I don't see why the latter shouldn't work when the former does.

Comment: Yes, I find it also very strange. From general point of view there's nothing different. Maybe the `$PSScriptRoot` has some specifics? After all it's not a variable defined manually inside the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For building paths use the [`Join-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/join-path?view=powershell-3.0) cmdlet:

```
$ExcelFile = Join-Path $PSScriptRoot ($File + '.xlsx')
```

In your particular case you could also go with a simple string with variables:

```
$ExcelFile = "${PSScriptRoot}\${File}.xlsx"
```

But `Join-Path` is the more resilient approach, because it [automatically takes care of the path separator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17146630/1630171) between the elements.

Answer (score 0):

Thought this might help someone

```
# Get Current working path
if($PSScriptRoot){$PSRootPath = $PSScriptRoot}Else{Try { $PSRootPath = (Split-Path $psISE.CurrentFile.FullPath -Parent)} Catch {$PSRootPath = (Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path -Parent)}}
```